# Installing patches through CI/CD

Tags: patch-configuration, azure-devops

We have XP1 installed in Azure PAAS in Sitecore 10 with CI/CD configured.

We deploy hotfixes and patches provided by Sitecore one by one through `ms-deploy`.
Now with time, we have too many patches, with few patches of 100MB. So, this step runs for a long.

We are looking to optimize it and looking for your suggestions.